# Java Removing String Problem (Please don't give any solutions with StringBuilder or BufferedWriter)

Tags: java, string, loops

Task: In this problem, you remove all occurrences of the removal string from the original string. Each time you take out the removal string you must also remove the letter that preceded the removal string. After you remove a string and its leading character, you must check to see if any more of the occurrence of the removal string exists.

The question: I don't understand why I keep getting this exception and how to fix it.
My input for the org is `fuxqwexqwertyxqwexqwertyrtyxqwertyrtyn`. My input for removal is `qwerty`.
My expected output should be fun.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 1, end 7, length 3
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3410)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1883)
    at Exercise8.remove(Exercise8.java:17)
    at Exercise8.main(Exercise8.java:10)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Sample input: ");
         String org = scan.nextLine();
         String removal = scan.nextLine();
         remove(org, removal);
    }

    private static void remove(String org, String removal) {
        for (int x = 0; x < org.length()-1; x++)
        {
            if (org.substring(x,x + removal.length()).equals(removal))
            {
                org = org.substring(0,x-1) + org.substring(x + removal.length(), org.length());
                x = 0;

            }
        }

        System.out.println(org);
    }
}
```

Comment: one thing, `org.substring(0,x-1)` should be `org.substring(0,x)`

Comment: I also want to remove the letter that precedes the occurrence of the removal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int x = 0; x < org.length()-removal.length(); x++)
    {
        if (org.substring(x,x + removal.length()).equals(removal))
        {
            org = org.substring(0,x-1) + org.substring(x + removal.length(), org.length());
            x = 0;

        }
    }
```

You need to take care that you don't start your substring at an invalid index.